# What should be the default value of non URL parameter in angular js route

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a state which has the second parameter as a non URL parameter which goes something like this:

```
$stateProvider.state('sample', {
            url: 'sample/:aId',
            params: {bId : null} //bId is not a part of URL
})
```

When I fire

```
$state.go({'sample',{aId:'123', bId:'345'}}) //bId as a non URL parameter
```

it works fine (i.e., bId = '345' can be retrieved from $stateParams object inside controller)
But if do

```
$state.go({'sample',{aId:'678'}}) //bId is not passed
```

**Issue**: *bId* is still the old one (i.e., bId = '345' when i retrieve inside controller as in above case)

**Questions**:

What should be the value of bId in this case ?

What if I have to send some information in URL as a non URL parameter ?